# Gradle 6.x - Could not create task of type 'SpotBugsTask'

Tags: gradle, migration

I'm migrating Gradle project from v 4.10.3 to 6.8 because I need relocatable cache. Here are the files https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/679a4922da4d63df1489655853051916
The system-wide Gradle is version 6.8. When I run "gradle clean build" I got following error:

```
└─$ gradle clean build       
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true

> Configure project :
ArtifactoryUser user: null
Using Java from /home/katya/java (version 11.0.2)
Detected development environment

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/home/katya/tmp_work/groovy-2.5.8_modified/gradle/quality.gradle' line: 149

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not create task ':spotbugsAntlr'.
   > Could not create task of type 'SpotBugsTask'.
      > Could not create an instance of type com.github.spotbugs.internal.SpotBugsReportsImpl.
         > org.gradle.api.reporting.internal.TaskReportContainer.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/gradle/api/Task;)V

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'groovy'.
> Could not create task ':spotbugsMain'.
   > Could not create task of type 'SpotBugsTask'.
      > Could not create an instance of type com.github.spotbugs.internal.SpotBugsReportsImpl.
         > org.gradle.api.reporting.internal.TaskReportContainer.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/gradle/api/Task;)V

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s

Publishing build scan...
```

Some deprecated Gradle features are mentioned, but I do not clearly understand what is going on, could you explain me? How to force this project build in Gradle 6.8?